# react-native project cannot find github repo of dependencies from new fork

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I'm new to Gradle and Android development, but I have a React Native project that relies on the "react-native-sqlite-2 (https://github.com/craftzdog/react-native-sqlite-2)" library, which itself depends on "sqlite-android" (specifically version 3.36.0). I want to make some custom changes to the "sqlite-android (https://github.com/requery/sqlite-android)" library and then incorporate those changes into my own fork of the "react-native-sqlite-2" repository.

```
react-native-sqlite-2/build.gradle
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation "com.github.requery:sqlite-android:3.36.0"
  ...
}
```

Could you kindly guide me through the steps to achieve this? I'd greatly appreciate your assistance in making these modifications and integrating them into my project.

I tried google, stackoverflow with all possible solutions, tips&tricks. I forked the projects made appropriate changes. Tried to integrade sqlite-android .aar file directly into react-native-sqlite2 but it failed with cannot include .aar or .jar. Then I tried to host it on local maven did not work. Then I tried jitpack, it is not generating any artifacts but my gradle build for react native project is failing unable to locate the repo